# Creating a Popup for new case assignment in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

When I create a new case and assign it to a user in salesforce, I want a popup to show up on their screen to show that they have a new case.  I have tried several different things but cannot get this to work.  Is this something anyone can help me with?!  Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a task as a reminder for the case assignee.  Then when the assignee logs in or when the due date comes they get a web pop-up.